# Add legend in igraph to annotate difference vertices size

Tags: r, legend, igraph

I have a graph in `igraph` with a vertex size that is coded for a value.
I wish to add a legend with symbols (points in my case) with different sizes.
I tried the following code

```
require(igraph)
er_graph <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 5/100)
value<-runif(100)
n<-6
size_vec<-seq_len(n)
sizeCut<-cut(value,n)
vertex.size<-size_vec[sizeCut]
plot(er_graph, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=vertex.size)
legend('topleft',legend=levels(sizeCut),pt.cex=size_vec,col='black')
```

but end with legend without symbols
[see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjAQ8.png)

Any sugestions how I go about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should set `pch` to some value to indicate which character you want to use for the bullets (see `?points` to check the possible values).
Also, you should scale the `pt.cex` values in order to make the bullets not too big for the legend, and use `pt.bg` to set the background color of the bullets, e.g.

```
# scaled between 1 and 2
scaled <- 1 + ((2-1) * (size_vec - min(size_vec) ) / (  max(size_vec) - min(size_vec) ) )
legend('topleft',legend=levels(sizeCut),pt.cex=scaled,col='black',pch=21, pt.bg='orange')
```

[image]

**EDIT :**

Unfortunately, calculating the right sizes of the bullets is not easy; a possible workaround is plotting white bullets then manually add the vertices to the legend in the same way they are plotted inside the plot.igraph function :

```
# N.B. /200 is taken from plot.igraph source code
a <- legend('topleft',legend=levels(sizeCut),pt.cex=size_vec/200,col='white',
            pch=21, pt.bg='white')
x <- (a$text$x + a$rect$left) / 2
y <- a$text$y
symbols(x,y,circles=size_vec/200,inches=FALSE,add=TRUE,bg='orange')
```

[image]

**Disclaimer**: this code heavily relies on the source code of plot.igraph function that might be changed in a future version of igraph. Probably you should search for another plot function for igraph which natively allows to add a legend.

Comment: That nice, but I want also that the size of the points in the legend will fit to the actual size of the points in the graph. How can I find the appropriate  scaling factor?

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking at this who wants a continuous scale for node sizes instead of a discrete scale then this is the code you need to do it:

```
require(igraph)
er_graph <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 5/100)
value<-runif(100)
sizeCut<- c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0)
sizeCutScale <- sizeCut*10
vertex.size<-value*10
plot(er_graph, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=vertex.size)
legend('topleft',legend=unique(sizeCut),pt.cex= sizeCutScale,col='black')
a <- legend('topleft',legend=unique(sizeCut),pt.cex=sizeCutScale/200,col='white',
            pch=21, pt.bg='white')
x <- (a$text$x + a$rect$left) / 2
y <- a$text$y
symbols(x,y,circles=sizeCutScale/200,inches=FALSE,add=TRUE,bg='orange')
```

[image]